# Regular Expressions and php

Tags: php, string

I have a form where users enter a URL. I need a regular expression to skip the part 'http://' if present. For example, if the user insert into the form: http://youtube.com I need to save only youtube.com.
 I don't know regular expressions. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Have you made an attempt?  Most "write my code for me" questions on SO die a slow death.

Comment: people like to answer easy ones for easy rep.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone! The problem was easier than i expect. I used the substring solution. Thanks!

Comment: Funny that these solutions got down-voted by some people who are not willing to give easy help ;)

Comment: @Franz: These easy questions are like war.

Comment: Ah, I got it. I should add that tag ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe a regular expression would be overkill here.  How about this?

```
$str = str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'),'',$str);
```

Comment: agreed...no need to check if it exists...just replace it.

Comment: +1. this is actually better than mine. And even better, if you make it `array('http://', 'https://')`.

Comment: what about ftp://, do you happen to have a full list of every valid protocol?

Comment: unless he wants to avoid stripping it out in the case of a string like 'example string that contains http:// in the middle of it because it is a comment explaining the syntax of a URL'.

Comment: @powtac - yeah, I thought about that, but thinking about the context of the question, a URL with an http:// in the query string would probably be some sneaky attempt at redirection and is likely unwanted anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind, that the string `http://` could occur twice or more times in an URL!

```
$parts = parse_url('http://youtube.com');
$url   = $parts['host'].$parts['path']; //.'?'.$parts['query'].'#'.$parts['fragment']
```

See [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

You do not really need regular expressions. This would be enough:

```
if (substr($str, 0, 7) == 'http://')
    $str = substr($str, 7);
else if (substr($str, 0, 8) == 'https://')
    $str = substr($str, 8);
```

EDIT: Added the `else if` part.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use substr to check if the string begins with 'http://' and remove that part; no regex.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it without a regex, since you don't know regexes, and just check if the index of the first found "http://" string (case insensitive) is at position 0, and if it is remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Not needed. However, if you want regex:

```
// get host name from URL
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i', $the_url, $matches);
$host = $matches[1];
```